# How to build archive with Cake(C# make)

Tags: c#, xamarin, cakebuild

I can build my xamarin project with cake by using this lines of codes:

```
MSBuild(projectDirectory + @"\MyProject.sln", configurator =>
        configurator.SetConfiguration(configuration)
            .SetVerbosity(Verbosity.Minimal)
            .SetPlatformTarget(PlatformTarget.MSIL)
            .WithTarget("Build")
            .WithProperty("OutputPath", buildDir));
```

But i want to create google play archive and appstore ipa. After that send this files to stores. How can i do this?

Comment: This seems like a duolicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956828/how-do-you-export-an-ipa-apk-when-using-cakebuild-and-xamarin

Comment: I can build ipa or apk file but i can not upload files to stores. I asked for how can i do this with cakebuild.

Comment: Ah apologies, I missed that bit :-(

Answer (score 1):

My question would be, if you did this command line currently, how would you do it?
You can scrape the command line statement and use [Start Process](http://cakebuild.net/dsl/process/) in your Cake script to run the command line utility.  The general rule with Cake, if you can command line it, you can execute it in a Cake script.  That said there is nothing to my knowledge in the DSL that currently communicates directly to the playstore.