# How do you export an IPA/APK when using CakeBuild and Xamarin ?

Tags: xamarin, fastlane, cakebuild

I am trying to use CakeBuild & FastLane to automate the build process for my Xamarin Project. I have a script that is working to execute a "build" command with Cake, but it does not output a IPA/APK file. Here is my current script

```
    MSBuild("./MyDirectory/MyProject.sln", settings =>
  settings.SetConfiguration("Release")
      .WithTarget("Build")
      .WithProperty("Platform", "iPhone")
      .WithProperty("BuildIpa", "true")
      .WithProperty("OutputPath", "bin/Release/")
      .WithProperty("TreatWarningsAsErrors", "false"));
```

The directory "bin/release" is always empty

Answer (score 2):

I had better luck producing ipa and apk files using [Cake.Xamarin](http://cakebuild.net/dsl/xamarin/).

That said, if you are building for iPhone, have you tired setting the configuration to "Release|iPhone"?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting your target to the name of your iOS project within the solution instead?

Keep in mind to replace `.` in the project name with `_` ...

So something like...

`.WithTarget ("MyProject_iOS")`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running this on a windows machine. Then you maybe have to specify your Xamarin Build Agent. But I'm not sure about this. Try to add the properties ServerAddress, ServerUser and ServerPassword like this:

```
MSBuild("./MyDirectory/MyProject.sln", settings =>
  settings.SetConfiguration("Release")
      .WithTarget("Build")
      .WithProperty("Platform", "iPhone")
      .WithProperty("BuildIpa", "true")
      .WithProperty("ServerAddress", "NAME_OF_YOUR_MAC")
      .WithProperty("ServerUser", "NAME_OF_YOUR_MAC_USER")
      .WithProperty("ServerPassword", "PASSWORD_OF_YOUR_MAC_USER")
      .WithProperty("OutputPath", "bin/Release/")
      .WithProperty("TreatWarningsAsErrors", "false"));
```